# working on array with async.parallel

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, asynchronous

I was working with async module in Node.js , I am stuck in the problem of getting the order of values from global array in async.parallel module.

```
function(callback)
{
let array = [url,url,url,url,url,url,url,url,url,url];

async.parallel([
    function(cb){
        //working on one url from array and then remove from array
    },
    function(cb){
        //working on one url from array and then remove from array
    },
    function(cb){
        //working on one url from array and then remove from array
    },
    function(cb){
        //working on one url from array and then remove from array
    },
    function(cb){
        //working on one url from array and then remove from array
    }
],function(error,result){
    if(error)
        callback(error);
    else{
        callback(null,true);
    }   
})
}
```

Each internal functions of async.parallel will call request module to get another html page and after extracting its url links,then again inserting those url links to global array "array".

I am not getting how do we know which array element is used by which function ?

Comment: Wouldn't [`map`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map) be more appropriate?

Comment: @cartant I want to use parallel only,each task is independent of each other

Comment: I think you need to be clearer regarding what you are trying to do. How does the number of functions in the `parallel` call relate to the number of elements in the array?

Comment: @cartant I just want to say that,there will be one array of urls.Then from that urls we will call request module in 5 different parallel functions..I don't want same url to called again and again.because we dont' know which element will be acccesed by that function

Answer (score 0):

There are two approachs possible.

One is the way you're doing,

```
async.parallel([
    function(cb){
        //working on one url from array and then remove from array
       arr[0] // 0th here
    },
    function(cb){
        //working on one url from array and then remove from array
          arr[1] // 1st here
    },
```

.
.
.
.
then you'll get the result as `[a,b,c,d,e,f]` where `a,b,c,d,e,f` refer to `0th,1st,2nd,3rd,4th` elements in the array

Other way of doing is through **Object of parallel methods instead of array**

```
async.parallel({
    0: function(cb){
        //working on one url from array and then remove from array
       arr[0] // 0th here
    },
    1: function(cb){
        //working on one url from array and then remove from array
          arr[1] // 1st here
    }
}, function(err, results) {
    // results is now equals to: {0: a, 1: b}
})
```

Comment: If we want to remove that element from array ... it is giving wrong result.

Comment: Where are you trying removing element from the array ?

Comment: I just want to say that,there will be one array of urls.Then from that urls we will call request module in 5 different parallel functions..I don't want same url to called again and again.because we dont' know which element will be acccesed by that function